# Can Mockito mocked class object calls the real method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Hi I have a mocked class and for the majority of its members I don't mind it returning the defaults but there could be some methods I want the mocked class object to use the real method, how do you configure this test? e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
    public int func1() {
        return 1;
    }
    public int func2() {
        return 2;
    }
    public int run() {
        return func1() + func2();
    }
}

public class MyTest {
    @Mock private MyClass mockedClass
    @Before public void setup() {initMocks(this);}
    @Test public void test() {
        int result = mockedClass.func2();//I want the real func2() to run
        assertEquals(2, result);
        result = mockedClass.run();//I want the real run() and func2() to run
        assertEquals(2, result);
    }
}
```

I dont want to use spy because I will have to setup *when* for the majority of all those methods I dont care.

Comment: http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenCallRealMethod%28%29

Comment: Nice! Didn't know this method, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [user3707125](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3707125/user3707125) mentioned in the comments, you can use [`thenCallRealMethod`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenCallRealMethod%28%29) or [`doCallRealMethod`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod%28%29), but beware that when called on mocks (instead of spies) *it will invoke the real method on an instance that has not been initialized*.

This means that all fields will be null, including final fields, and any initialization you put into constructors will not have happened. This makes it a poor choice if the method depends on any state, and a very poor choice if the real method you're calling is your unit under test.

Unless your method is effectively static, or delegates to instance methods that you've stubbed with Mockito, you may find it safer to only call real methods on properly-initialized spies.

Comment: Yeah nice pointing out the side effects. In my case its a little helper function, so I am still good. Thanks for putting this up as an answer, obviously picked yours :)